# Hyperbolic area proof

Tags: calculus

Prove that:
$$\underset{D\ }{\\ \int \int} e^{\frac{x-y}{x+y}}dxdy=\frac{\sinh 1}{2}$$
D is triangle $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$.

How should I approach this proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transform to the coordinates

$$u=x+y$$
$$v=x-y$$
$$dx \, dy = \frac12 du \, dv$$

You do this because, if you draw $D$, you will see that it may consist of pieces of lines $x+y=c$, where $c \in [0,1]$.

Then the integral is

$$\frac12 \int_0^1 du \, \int_{-u}^u dv \, e^{v/u}$$

Should be easy now.